# SQL Search entity by Field or by Inherited Field

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have these tables:

```
Config
ID
TYPE - number (possible values 0,1,2)

Block
CONFIG_ID

Apartment
CONFIG_ID
BLOCK_ID

Room
CONFIG_ID
APARTMENT_ID
```

Now, the config for Apartment and Room **can be inherited** from the parent.

**Inheritance logic:**

- If for Room the CONFIG_ID is null it means we use the value from Apartment, but if Apartment also inherits we use the value from Block.
- Also if Room have a CONFIG_ID BUT only one config field is NULL, it also means that only that field is inherited. (so for example Room has a config_id = 4, and the TYPE in config 4 is NULL, it means the type is inherited)

  Example:
  Room "Kitchen" has CONFIG_ID = NULL
  Apartment "VIP Apartment" has a CONFIG_ID != NULL with TYPE = 2
  So the Kitchen TYPE is NULL which means the actual value is 2 (inherited from Apartment)

What I want is a **SQL query** to search Rooms by their TYPE **(even if its null so inherited)**.

So if I search for TYPE = 2 the Room 'Kitchen' above should be found, because it inherits from Apartment.

I can't really figure this out. I tried with 3 joins on each Block/Apartment/Room but the Config I need can come from different table everytime. And I don't know how to conditionally join the config on each table.

Pseudocode for the query:

```
 (room.config.TYPE is Xx or (room.config.type is null and (apartment.config.type = Xx or (apartment.config.type is null and block.config.type = Xx))))

Block 
id=1, name='Block1', config_id = NULL
Apartment 
id=1, name='Apartment1', block_id=1, config_id = 1 
Room
id=1, name='Room1-inherited', apartment_id = 1, config_id = NULL 
id=2, name='Room2-actual', apartment_id = 1, config_id = 2

Config
id=1, type=2 // apartment's config
id=2, type=2 // room2's config
```

Expected result when search for Rooms with type 2:

```
Both Room1 (inherited type 2 from Apartment)
 and Room2 (actual type in its own config)
```

Comment: School work? Can you add sample table data and also expected result?

Comment: It's not school work, is a usecase on a project I work on. You make me think it's easy to solve by asking if is school work, but I can't figure it out, thats why I posted. Also edited the question with a expected result. Hope it helps you, thanks.